# Firefox private window: restore closed tab in active session

Tags: firefox, history

As far as I concern, when you first enter private mode, firefox creates a temporary session and any private windows opened after that will be assign to that session (hence cookies are shared within private mode instances.)

Suppose I have two instances of firefox in private mode. If I closed a tab in an instance I could restore it in the same instance by `Ctrl+Shift+T` (it works in private mode.) If I closed one instance but hadn't destroyed the session (the is another instance still opened), can I restore closed tabs in a different instance? If firefox keeps track of recently closed tabs, than it also keeps track of history, can I see my private mode history if I had an opened instance of it?

Comment: I think Recently Closed Tabs is specific to a window/instance. Even in regular Firefox, not private, I cannot restore a tab from a window that was already closed.

Comment: @MC10 agreed, but if cookies are shared within the session, history should too.  If one had an access to the session history, one could easily achieve the same effect as by `Ctrl+Shift+T`. And yet `Ctrl+H` in private mode shows only ordinary history.